# grid selection lost after refresh

Tags: extjs, grid, refresh, selection

In extjs i have a grid. This grid is refreshed every ** seconds. To keep the grid selection I use this:

```
     Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selectedRecords: [],
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.getStore().on('beforeload', this.rememberSelection, this);
        this.getView().on('refresh', this.refreshSelection, this);
    },
    rememberSelection: function (selModel, selectedRecords) {
        if (!this.rendered || Ext.isEmpty(this.el)) {
            return;
        }

        this.selectedRecords = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        this.getView().saveScrollState();
    },
    refreshSelection: function () {
        if (0 >= this.selectedRecords.length) {
            return;
        }

        var newRecordsToSelect = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            record = this.getStore().getById(this.selectedRecords[i].getId());
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
                newRecordsToSelect.push(record);
            }
        }

        this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
        Ext.defer(this.setScrollTop, 30, this, [this.getView().scrollState.top]);
    }
});
```

but this doesn't work in one grid and i can't find out why. This is the refresh function:

```
refreshSeconds = refreshRate * 1000;
refreshData = {
    run: function () {
        NL.store.load();
    },
    interval: refreshSeconds
}
Ext.TaskManager.start(refreshData)
```

And this is the grid (without columns)

```
 var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
   autoscroll: true,
    region: 'center',
    store: NL.store,
    multiSelect: false,
    stateful: true,
    loadMask: false,
    stateId: 'stateGridEvents',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },
    columns: [{
```

But when the store is reloaded the selection is lost. What do i need to change?

Comment: Are you using 4.1.1? If yes, this is a bug that was introduce to this version - it didn't exist in 4.1.0; Let me know if you want me to post a possible fix.

Comment: @Izhaki, could you please post your possible fix? I seem to have stumbled upon this bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try using standard features first:

```
Ext.define('PersistentSelectionGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    viewConfig: {
        preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Using this option does not preserve selection.

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected records use

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
```

In your code, 's' was missing in getSelections(). You might got a script error for this.

I think the below line your code should be modified as,

```
Your code::     this.getView().on('refresh', this.refreshSelection, this);
Modified code:  this.getStore().on('afterload', this.refreshSelection, this);
```

So that the records get selected after the data is loaded.

Comment: You can also try selecting the records in viewready() event of grid panel